# How to add email address to string in Perl? ( "@" character )

Tags: perl

I have this following Perl code in the CloudBees online devops platform:

```
my $formattedUserEmail = $[UserEmail];
    
$additionalTestParameters .= "ECJOBLink,$jobLink;ECJOBId,$[jobId];EcJobCounter,$jobCounter,PFUser,$formattedUserEmail";
```

It's deployed as the following Perl code:

```
my $formattedUserEmail = dave.adam@site.com; 
    
$additionalTestParameters .= "ECJOBLink,$jobLink;ECJOBId,1111;EcJobCounter,$jobCounter,PFUser,$formattedUserEmail";
```

But when the code runs, it results in errors, i believe because of the `dave.adam@site.com` email address, specifically the `@` character, which is a special symbol in Perl.

```
Array found where operator expected at ... line 32, at end of line
syntax error at .... line 32, near "adam@site"
Global symbol "@site" requires explicit package name at C.... line 32.
Execution of ..... aborted due to compilation errors.
```

How can I fix my code so that the email var gets added to the `$additionalTestParameters` string?

Comment: How is defined `$[UserEmail]` ?

Comment: Is that some kind of code that's interpolated before being run? If so, it needs quotes in the final `my` definition.

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm running the code on cloudbees, an online devops platform. @GillesQuénot is defined beforehand, before the code runs, the second code block is an example of what the var value is

Comment: `$[UserEmail]` is not Perl??? Is it some kind of template?  `'$[UserEmail]'` will do as long as the value doesn't contain any single quotes or backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$[UserEmail]` looks suspicious.  Maybe influenced by your [python](/questions/tagged/python) background.

If it's a `HASH` (like Python's dict), it should be `${'UserEmail'}`.

`$[UserEmail]` is for a `ARRAY` member and `UserEmail` should be a **numeric** key.

---

Always:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in all of your scripts, it will helps for coding errors:

```
Array found where operator expected at reply input line 1, near "adam@site"
Bareword "dave" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at reply input line 1.
syntax error at reply input line 1, near "adam@site"
Global symbol "@site" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @site"?) at reply input line 1.
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at reply input line 7.
```

Comment: the line `my $formattedUserEmail = dave.adam@site.com; ` is just an example of what the value looks like, the actual value is from $[UserEmail];

Comment: @POVR2 Please wrap `$[UserEmail]` with quotes so it looks like `'$[UserEmail]'`

Comment: Perl can allow extremely lax definitions of strings without quotes, but this is not a good idea, and `use strict` will scold you for doing so.

Comment: Re "*`$[UserEmail]` looks suspicious.*", Cause it's not Perl. The first snippet is a template used to generate the second.

Comment: @ikegami, OP never said it's a template usage and moreover, as far as he accepted this answer, looks like that was only a syntax error. OP have a python background, and I think he try to use Python syntax here. So templating looks like an assumption from your side.

Comment: I never said they said it was a template.  They were indeed quite unclear about it. And that's why I had to tell you. But it's still the case.

Comment: I never said they said it was a template.  They were indeed quite unclear about it. And that's why I had to tell you. But it's still the case. That's why there's two snippets. The one in the source base, and the one that's actually run (as the OP said, though unclearly). They're not two different programs, as you seem to have assumed.

Comment: Yes, it was a syntax error: The missing quotes. You very confusingly somehow removed that from your answer, though. That's what prompted my clarification. Python variables don't look anything like `$[UserEmail]`. It would be just `UserEmail`. No, the OP said was part of the cloudbees devops paltform.

Comment: Do note that your theory that `$[name]`  is wrong is itself wrong, since the OP showed that `$[jobId]` *works*. The only issue is the missing quotes.  (And the lack of `use strict;`. Nice catch.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you are using some unspecified templating language. To achieve what you want, you will need to get it to convert the text you want to provide (`dave.adam@site.com`) into a Perl string literal (`'dave.adam@site.com'`).

If the string doesn't contain any quotes or backslashes, you can get away with using

```perl
my $formattedUserEmail = '$[UserEmail]';
```

In this case, this will produce

```perl
my $formattedUserEmail = 'dave.adam@site.com';
```

Note that this is unsafe. If the source is untrusted, it could inject malicious code. Without knowing more about the templating language, I can't provide a safe solution.